# Link="preload" added but not detected by Pagespeed

Tags: css, wordpress, preload, pagespeed-insights

Pagespeed Insights recommends preloading certain font files to speed up page load. I have added the code within my  element, but Pagespeed still does not detect it. I tried all the fixes mentioned on other answers:

- Using crossorigin attribute(with anonymous)
- Using the insert headers/footers plugin
- Loading other font types like .woff, .eot

Here is the link to [the page](https://productiveclub.com/polgar-sisters-story/). This page is only an example. The same problem exists on all other posts too where Pagespeed mentions:

```
Consider using `<link rel=preload>` to prioritize fetching resources that are currently requested later in page load. Learn more.
URL
Potential Savings
…fonts/johannes-font.ttf(productiveclub.com)
2,670 ms
```

The multiple preloads right now is only for testing. The same error persists when I retain only one preload statement.

Can anyone understand what's wrong in my code here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just thought I would see if there is anything else you want adding to the answer seeing as you bountied the question or if you have had chance to try what I suggested yet?

Answer (score 5):

When you actually load the font it has a `?` at the end of it.

This will in some circumstances then clear the cache and load a fresh version of the file, undoing any preloading you have done / treat it as a different file.

`url(/wp-content/themes/johannes/assets/fonts/johannes-font.ttf?) format('truetype')` located in one of the minified CSS files.

You are also preloading it more than once (line 7 and line 199 in the HTML) so you will get a console error, not directly related but important to fix either way.

> The resource https://productiveclub.com/wp-content/themes/johannes/assets/fonts/johannes-font.ttf was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

**for clarity** - as far as a browser is concerned `fonts/johannes-font.ttf` does not equal `fonts/johannes-font.ttf?` so you aren't actually preloading the file as far as the browser is concerned. Remove the `?` from your URL and it should work as expected.